# Can we get timestamps added to the CoC page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, code-of-conduct

In the same way we have for the [Privacy Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy) at the bottom of the page:

> Last update: November 8, 2018

Can we do this for the CoC page going ahead on all sites?

Comment: While this doesn't yet exist, let's have a bot that archives every day's Code of Conduct to the WayBackMachine.

Comment: What is the purpose of including the date? For the Privacy Policy, I believe it is there for legal reasons that I don't claim to fully understand. The CoC is a social agreement and doesn't really have any legal components to it.

Comment: @DavidK I think at least one fired moderator begs to differ ...

Comment: @DavidK one purpose would be transparency; so people know when the last update was to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), with the [CoC](/conduct) [update](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/10/iterating-on-inclusion/):

[image: Footer of the new CoC with the text: "Last update: 2019-10-10"]

Comment: That looks like a blog posting to me, and not the Code of Conduct Page.  Can you update with an explicit link?

Comment: I’ll do tomorrow. The link intended to link to the update rather than the CoC.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Done.

Answer (score 7):

This is a super reasonable request and we put it in while we were in the area.

Thanks for the suggestion, it's now live. Note: the date format is different from the legal pages because the CoC is localized and we don't have the legal page's format in the localization bits. We'll probably re-visit the other pages and standardize the date format.

Comment: It would be awesome to see the version controls that Sara Chipps linked in her blog about them. Not sure if that's doable, but might as well mention it. Makes changes easy to note

Comment: @Machavity not sure I'm following - do you mean screenshots of VCS or something else?

Comment: [This image](https://149351115.v2.pressablecdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/no-big-1.jpg) is on the blog. Having the VCS syntax highlighting helps note what was changed. I hate it when companies announce a change, give a synopsis, and then leave it to you to figure out what in the wall of text actually changed.

Comment: I'm glad to see devs starting to interact with the community again, I hope you all keep it up.

Comment: @Machavity ah gotcha - thanks for clarifying! It's not something we can easily do since it's just Razor `.csthml` when it comes down to it, perhaps piping the diff from git into something is doable but we'd had to build a...thing. We're not really setup to do that (e.g. the build doesn't push _back_ to git in any way right now), but it may be something for the future. I suggest raising it here on meta as a feature request so we can track it and give it some priority if it's something many people want...we may get some suggestions on how to better do it as well.

Comment: @NickCraver [Done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335040/show-code-of-conduct-and-other-terms-of-service-within-version-control-highlight)