# Show Code of Conduct and other terms of service within version control highlighting

Tags: feature-request, terms-of-service, code-of-conduct

I wanted to highlight something I think SO got right today. Within [the blog entry about the Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/10/iterating-on-inclusion/), Sara Chipps shows VCS highlighted changes to the CoC

[image: VCS CoC]

This is a simple quality-of-life change, but it makes it MUCH easier to tell what has actually changed. Bonus points for putting the whole thing into a Github-esque setup so we could see the revisions over time.

Comment: + for github or any other RCS.

Comment: I'd slightly reframe the question as: "SO almost got it right; please show the diff accurately and/or use a public RCS/VCS". It's _almost_, because [the actual diff was this](https://gist.github.com/ento/1d333bc55d685f96cb05691d9cbbb3bb#file-coc-diff-L36-L49), as recorded by the wayback machine. The blog post 1. doesn't show the old lines, and 2. doesn't highlight the changed words exactly (also when there's only additions, you don't highlight words). The way the format is used, it's only part of the coding-flavored writing style the post is going for, not the actual diff.

Comment: That blog did not get it right. I'm pretty sure the old text wasn't `When in doubt, don.`